# Some styled-components props passed to HTML tags, other not

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am looking for a pattern or some explanation why some styled-components props are passed and rendered in the HTML and other not. Simple example:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: ${props => props.direction};
  flex: ${props => props.flex};
`;
```

Then when I use it like:

```
<Container direction="column" flex="2">
```

The output of HTML that I can check in developer tools is like:

```
<div direction="column" class="sc-Ajrsh">
```

I know that I can name the direction prop with `$` symbol like `$direction` and it solves the issue, but what is the pattern of when to add this symbol and when not to? I don't know any `direction` HTML attributes (only the [dir](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp) one) so probably this is not the case. The same happened to me with `nested` prop name and some others (and for some I am getting some warning in console, while for some no warning...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [styled components docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props):

> If the styled target is a simple element (e.g. styled.div), styled-components passes through any known HTML attribute to the DOM.

Internally, it looks like `styled-components` uses the `@emotion/is-prop-valid` package to figure out what props are "known" and not. Here is [the list of props from source code that are considered "known"](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/blob/516fe458058c9ec8218740472b301e935801ebbc/packages/is-prop-valid/src/props.js#L281) - you can see that "direction" is included because it is a [valid prop for svgs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/direction).